# How do I activate the Goddess Cubes under the giant tree in Faron Woods?

Tags: zelda-skyward-sword

I just finished the first dungeon in *Skyward Sword*.  After learning about the Goddess Cubes, I went back to Faron Woods because I remembered seeing one, but didn't know what it was at the time.  As I entered Faron Woods from the Northeast, out of the Deep Woods, directly under the tree in front of me *and* just to the left of that are two Goddess Cubes.  ([Map here.](http://www.zelda-skyward-sword.com/faron-woods-map/))

I wandered all around the tree and could not figure out how to get up to them.  The only clue I found was something that looked like a square bullseye.  I tried running the beetle into it and hitting it with the slingshot, but nothing happened.

How do I reach and activate these cubes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You won't be able to access them yet.  The earliest you can would be your second visit to the forest...

> after you have obtained the **Water Dragon's Scale** allowing you to swim.  You'll have to climb the tree from the inside so you could drop down and reach those cubes.

The target you are referring to is a target for the **Clawshots**.  These come even later in the game and allows you to zoom up to the target.

> These are obtained by passing the second goddess trial.

Comment: That's what I thought.  Thanks for hiding any potential spoilers.